# How to switch x axis with y after pandas groupby plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Here's an example:

```
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
g = titanic.groupby('embark_town').count()['survived']
g.plot(kind='bar')
```

[town x count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3B1q.png)

I'm trying for a while to make it count x town, how can I do it?

Comment: Try using:
`g.plot(kind='barh')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply `kind='barh'` instead of `kind='bar'` in the `g.plot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
g = titanic.groupby('embark_town').count()['survived']
g.plot(kind='barh')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Or you can use `g.plot.barh()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
g = titanic.groupby('embark_town').count()['survived']
g.plot.barh()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output : [image]

Comment: Thank you, I had the documentation opened but I was looking for a solution using the other arguments, so it went overlooked.

Comment: @Al777 Sure. It can happen to any of us. It would be nice if you  could accept (through check sign) the answer. It helps others to confirm that this solution works.